# Custom View with MVP in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mvp

I have custom View with presenter, simplified version here:

```
public class CustomLayout extends FrameLayout implements CustomContract.CustomView {

    @Inject
    CustomPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        super.onViewAdded(child);
        presenter.bindView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        presenter.unbindView(this);
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    public void setData(@NonNull MyModel myModel) {
        presenter.onInit(myModel);
    }
}
```

And I want to use it in RecyclerView.
And set data in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull List<Item> items,
                                int position,
                                @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,
                                @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    Item item = item.get(position);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = (CustomViewHolder) holder;

    viewHolder.customLayout.setData(item.data());
}
```

It works only once, after scrolling my CustomLayout detached from window and when I return back it crashes, because presenter has already unbinded and new one hasn't binded (onViewAdded isn't called).

Can you help me please?